Tried to include string boot in an already existing project and i get this error
package com.weatherapp.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WeatherAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WeatherAppApplication.class, args);
    }

}

Error: Main method not found in class com.weatherapp.demo.WeatherAppApplication, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application


Probably missing spring boot maven plugin, go over to start.spring.io, generate a project and explore how pom.xml should look like

If you want to use JavaFX with Spring Boot you need to extend javafx.application.Application.
@SpringBootApplication
public class WeatherAppApplication extends javafx.application.Application
...

Have a look at https://medium.com/@samydavic/javafx-application-with-spring-boot-2b7c3374e675 for a full example
